# JavaScript Create New Drop Down List, add Options to Select from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm working on a UserScript that adds Buttons to a webpage. One of the buttons I'm working on when clicked will create a popup div. I'm trying to create a dynamic Select/Option dropdown list within the popup, with the options coming from an Array. However, I keep getting errors and was looking for some help in getting this to work. Here's a modified version of my code that deals with the creation of the option & select.

```
var button = document.createElement('button'),
button.onclick = prompt;
function prompt() {
    var blockingDiv = document.createElement('div');
    blockingDiv.id = 'PopupBackground';
    var divPopup = document.createElement('div');
    divPopup.id = 'DivPopup';
    var logo = document.createElement('div');
    logo.id = 'Logo';
    var content = document.createElement('div');
    content.id = 'Content';
    var dropList = document.createElement('select');
    dropList.id = 'DropListSelect';
    dropList.name = 'DropListSelect';
    content.appendChild(DropList);
    var dropListOption = document.createElement('option');
    dropListOption.id = 'DropListOptions';
    dropListOption.name = 'DropListOptions';
    dropList.appendChild(dropListOption);
    var options = 
    [
        {
            'text': 'Select',
            'value': '',
            'defaultSelected': true,
            'selected': true
        },
        {
            'text': 'Text 1',
            'value': 'A',
            'defaultSelected': false,
            'selected': false
        },
        {
            'text': 'Text 2',
            'value': 'B',
            'defaultSelected': false,
            'selected': false
        },
        {
            'text': 'Text 3',
            'value': 'C',
            'defaultSelected': false,
            'selected': false
        }
    ];
    var select = document.querySelector('#DropListSelect');
    dropListOption.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= options.length - 1; i++) {
        var type = options[i];
        dropListOption[i] = new Option(type.text, type.value, type.defaultSelected, type.selected)
    }
```

When I click the button I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'length') at HTMLButtonElement.prompt`.

Comment: It would help us if you could explain what the errors are.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the error I'm getting.

Comment: dropListOption is an "option".  It has no "length" property.  It seems you are trying to create a new option for each element in options array.  You will need to create an option each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my code to the following works now. Thank you [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james) for getting me on the right track!

```
var button = document.createElement('button'),
button.onclick = prompt;
function prompt() {
    var blockingDiv = document.createElement('div');
    blockingDiv.id = 'PopupBackground';
    var divPopup = document.createElement('div');
    divPopup.id = 'DivPopup';
    var logo = document.createElement('div');
    logo.id = 'Logo';
    var content = document.createElement('div');
    content.id = 'Content';
    var dropList = document.createElement('select');
    dropList.id = 'DropListSelect';
    dropList.name = 'DropListSelect';
    content.appendChild(DropList);
    var options = 
    [
        {
            'text': 'Select',
            'value': '',
            'defaultSelected': true,
            'selected': true
        },
        {
            'text': 'Text 1',
            'value': 'A',
            'defaultSelected': false,
            'selected': false
        },
        {
            'text': 'Text 2',
            'value': 'B',
            'defaultSelected': false,
            'selected': false
        },
        {
            'text': 'Text 3',
            'value': 'C',
            'defaultSelected': false,
            'selected': false
        }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i <= options.length - 1; i++) {
        var dropListOption = document.createElement('option');
        dropListOption.id = 'DropListOptions';
        dropListOption.name = 'DropListOptions';
        var type = options[i];
        dropListOption.appendChild(new Option(type.text, type.value, type.defaultSelected, type.selected));
        dropList.appendChild(dropListOption);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
var select = document.querySelector('#DropListSelect');
select.innerHTML = ""; // delete all existing options
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var type = options[i];
    select.appendChild(new Option(type.text, type.value, type.defaultSelected, type.selected));
}
```

Comment: Now I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') at HTMLButtonElement.prompt`.

Comment: So changing it to this gets me further, however, it's showing all of the options on one line in the drop down menu instead of multiple options that are able to be selected:
`for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var type = options[i];
    dropListOption.appendChild(new Option(type.text, type.value, type.defaultSelected, 
    type.selected));
    dropList.appendChild(dropListOption);
}`